# Hadoop 2.0 ApplicationMaster vs NodeManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am having trouble identifying the differences between the *ApplicationMaster* and *NodeManager* in the Hadoop 2.0 architecture.

I know that the ApplicationMaster is responsible for running the *map* and *reduce* tasks and it retrieves containers to run these tasks by coordinating with the ResourceManager.

But I am confused on the purpose of the NodeManager. Does the NodeManager create the containers for the ApplicationMaster (to run those map and reduce tasks) or does the ResourceManager create the containers for the ApplicationMaster (to run those map and reduce tasks) and the NodeManager just manages the health of the node, securely place files and directories needed by containers for the ApplicationMaster, and monitor the container's resource usage, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResourceManager(one per cluster) - arbitrates resources among all the applications.

NodeManager - responsible for containers launch, monitoring their resource usage (cpu, memory, disk, network) and reporting it to the ResourceManager/Scheduler.

So, in answer to your question, ResourceManager doesn't launch containers itself it finds the suitable NodeManager that can do that.

Some pictures and links with more details bellow.

[YARN Architecture](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) from official Hadoop docs:

[image]

[Anatomy of a YARN Application Run](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781491901687/ch04.html)(from "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" by Tom White):

[image]

Comment: But the resource manager will first launch the container to run the application master when the client submits the YARN application. Correct? Then after that, the application master interacts with the resource manager to get containers to run the Map and Reduce tasks and these containers are created by the NodeManager. Correct?

Comment: As I understand ResourceManager doesn't launch any containers itself, it just serves resource requests "redirecting" those requests to NodeManagers which have needed resources.

Comment: So NodeManager launches Application master containers as well as usual map/reduce job containers.