# How was the container created and how does it work?

Tags: hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager, nodemanager

First of all thank you for your answer, whether it is useful or not.
I don't quite understand Container, the problem is as follows

1. Is Contatiner a component of NodeManager?
2. Is the Contatiner created with NodeManager?
3. When NodeManager or MRAppMaster wants to start a Contatiner, do you only need to configure it?
4. Is there a collection of available resources in the scheduler? Will some resources be allocated for running jobs every time? Is it like cutting a ham?
5. I want to know how a Contatiner is started or created in ResourceManager.

I hope the answer can be simpler and easier to understand, and it is best to have a picture show.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you already searched for an answer to your question, [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhadoop%5D+%5Byarn%5D+container+nodemanager) or [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=yarn+container+nodemanager)? It seems very close to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552301/hadoop-2-0-applicationmaster-vs-nodemanager) on SO, and [YARN's official doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManager.html) seems helpful too. If not, try to explain what you are still missing

Comment: Thank you, sir, I just read the official document and the links you gave me, but it didn't help me, I reorganized my question, I hope this can make my question more clear.I reposted it, but I don’t know if there are any grammatical errors in these sentences. (I mean the sentence describing the problem);https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294017/how-does-work-the-resource-scheduler-in-resource-manager-work-with-nodemanager-a

Comment: You could have edited the present question instead of opening a new one. I commented over there